# Record H.264 Stream from SDP file

Tags: c#, h.264, sdp

I am trying to figure out how to access an H.264 stream and then record it to an MP4. The recording part I can do as I have done this in the past with DirectShow however I just don't know how to access the stream from the parameters in the SDP file. I have used Streamcoders MediaSuite.NET before for RTSP and they seem to support SDP but I'm at a loss as to convert the parameters into a necessary Decoder object. The following are the contents within the SDP:

```
v=0
o=- 1 8 IN IP4 192.168.1.17
s=mnt-1890335646-stream1-high
i=H264 session of mnt-1890335646-stream1-high
u=http://192.168.1.17
c=IN IP4 239.1.12.39/64/1
t=0 0
m=video 5006/1 RTP/AVP 102
i=Video stream
c=IN IP4 239.1.12.39/64/1
a=fmtp:102 width=1920;height=1080;depth=0;framerate=0;fieldrate=0;
a=framerate:0
a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to use this information with Streamcoders (preferably), or another managed library?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MainConcept's Network DirectShow filters, I can read the SDP file and pull in a stream.